# Offset a text block from the main grid by half the leading

Tags: context, grid-typesetting

In my attempt below I can almost achieve the correct offset if it were not for the descenders in the last line of the text block. Let's assume that the leading in the text block is identical to the global one.

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\showgrid


\starttext

\input ward

% Without descenders the baseline is offset by half a line :-)
\startlinecorrection
    This is a line without descenders.
    \blank[halfline]
\stoplinecorrection

\input ward

% Even for many lines :-)
\startlinecorrection
    \dorecurse{10}{This is a line without descenders. }
    \blank[halfline]
\stoplinecorrection

\input ward

% This just pushes the line down to the next grid line :-(
\startlinecorrection
    \blank[halfline]
    This is a line without descenders.
\stoplinecorrection

\input ward

% Any descender pushes the baseline up, away from the sweet spot between the grid lines :-(
\startlinecorrection
    This is a special line with descenders.
    \blank[halfline]
\stoplinecorrection

\input ward

\stoptext
```

Something like this should do:

1. Determine the depth d of the last line
2. Insert vertical space = .5*\baselineskip - d

How would I do that? Is there a better solution to this offset problem?